# Creating .pdf with pdfkit no save options

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, pdfkit

In application using nodejs, express and pdfkit am trying to create pdf.

Code that generates pdf is:

```js
exports.CreatePdfff = async function (req, res) {
    const doc = new PDFDocument;
    
    //doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf')); // write to PDF
    doc.pipe(res);                                       // HTTP response

    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');   // download file

    // add stuff to PDF here using methods described below...
    doc.text('Hello world!');

    // finalize the PDF and end the stream
    doc.end();
};
```

This is my router

```
router.get('/createpdf', filter_controller.CreatePdfff);
```

So if in the browser I call this

> /createpdf

I get the window which ask me where I want to save the pdf file, but if I call the same router from here

```js
$('#filterCreatePdf').on('click', function(event) {
    $.get('/createpdf', function(data) {
        
    });   
});
```

Then I don't get any window asking where to save the file.

Why in one case I get the desired output but in the other not?
How to get the option for user to select desired place for saving the document?

What is the best way to generate a pdf file in nodejs and serve it to the client?

UPDATE!

In ajax call for `$.get('/createpdf', function(data) }   });`   I get this pdf stream

```js
%PDF-1.3
%����
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
```

But I still can't show the pop-up window to save the file or even to show the pdf data. Any suggesstion?

Comment: `$.get` is just a standard AJAX request, and you can not trigger a download dialog directly in that scenario, _because_ it is a background request. `router.get` probably has some in-built magic to detect this was a “downloadable” response, and then _creates_ a download from it using the available client-side techniques.

Comment: Pdf stream is created with the call to the router.get('/createpdf, ...) and the success function is needed to show/interpert the data. Do I understand this correctly @CBroe

Comment: The `exports.CreatePdfff` method shown above appears to trigger a “normal” download, by specifying the appropriate headers. That will work for a _direct_ request, but not for an AJAX request in the background. Either `router.get` causes a direct request somehow, or it must do something else with the response, if it makes a background request as well.

Comment: @CBroe can you explain more in details. I am new to this and don't understand all. Maybe do you have some exaples? I tried doinin with blob and creating a url but it is not working.

Comment: If you only need to make a _GET_ request, then why are you using AJAX for this in the first place? Assign the URL to `location.href` instead, then this will be a _foreground_ request, and (assuming the server still responds with the correct headers) will automatically trigger the download dialog as desired …

Comment: Even if I do it like this

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", '/filters/createpdf', true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );

and in ProcessRequest do it like console.log I get  
%PDF-1.3
%����
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<

Comment: Yeah, that would be the binary content of the PDF then. But with XMLHttpRequest it’s still a background request.

Comment: Yes with XMLHttpRequest I made request to server. What do you mean with a foreground request @CBroe?

Comment: Well, the opposite of a background request - which any AJAX / Fetch request would be. Submit a form normally, click a link - those are the kind of actions that cause a normal, “foreground” request. In those cases the browser will present the download dialog automatically, if the response headers indicate that it is not a type of content it can display directly.

Comment: So you mean something like this:   
var link=document.createElement('a');
var x='/filters/createpdf';  
    link.href = x;
    link.click(); 

This gives me option to save a pdf file whic is generated in that path previosuly triggered with $.get('/createpdf', ...).